# Summation underlying symmetric group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, permutations

I know this summation has two term.How can we write ?
 Asuume that $\sigma(1)=1, \sigma(2)=2$ ,$$\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{2}}  \prod\limits_{i=1}^2 d_{\sigma(i)}(x_{i})=\sum\limits_{\sigma \in S_{2}} d_{\sigma(1)}(x_{1})d_{\sigma(2)}(x_{2})=\mathord? $$

Comment: The question goes very well with your user name :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetric group on two elements, $S_2$, has itself two elements (so two terms), namely 
$$ \sigma_1 \colon 1 \mapsto 1, 2 \mapsto 2, \qquad 
\sigma_2 \colon 1 \mapsto 2, 2 \mapsto 1 $$
hence,
$$ \sum_{\sigma\in S_2}\prod_{i=1}^2 d_{\sigma(i)}(x_i) 
  = d_1(x_1)d_2(x_2) + d_2(x_1)d_1(x_2) $$

Comment: martini thx a lot :).I learn it this afternoon,thanks though.